# Codename One Debug Builds on iOS 15

Tags: codenameone, ios15

We have an app running on iOS that we only distribute in Debug mode to specific users.

After our last round of updates, the app refuses to install with a message 'Failed to install application'

Pulling the logs from the device give the message 'Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement'

When checking the plist file in the .ipa the application-identifier is present and correct.

We do have the new zsign build hint. Other iOS build hint we currently have are,

```
codename1.arg.ios.zsign=true
codename1.arg.ios.xcode_version=12.4
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=false
codename1.arg.ios.debug.teamId=**********
codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation=true
codename1.arg.ios.release.distributionMethod=app-store
codename1.arg.ios.testFlight=true
codename1.arg.ios.debug.distributionMethod=development

codename1.arg.java.version=8
```

Please assist

Comment: Do you have access to a Mac?
Can you try to install it while connected with xcode device inspector active so you can look at the logs. Usually there's a more detailed error message there.

Comment: Fortunately we do not have access to a Mac.  It seems to be related to the Provisioning Profile from Apple. We have one app that works fine on iOS15. I took the app that does not work, simply changed its package name and used the Provisioning Profile from the working app, and it installs fine. We haven't figured out yet what make that one profile special as we have a number of apps and only one of them install on 15.   P.S.  We got Test Flight going and distributing through there works fine

Comment: Do you still have an older device lying around. Does it still work?

Comment: It is still working perfectly on iOS 7 up to 14

Comment: Comparing the working provisioning profile with the non-working one.  What are the differences between the entitlements of the corresponding app IDs in Apple's developer console?