# Codenameone debug build cannot be installed on iOS 15 device

Tags: codenameone, ios15

I had the problem, that the debug build for two apps could not be installed on an iOS 15 device. I found this post, which helped me to solve the problem for one of the apps:
[Codename One iOS 15 Debug Build Won't Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289761/codename-one-ios-15-debug-build-wont-open)

But the other app has still the problem that the debug build cannot be installed on an iOS 15 device (Error: "The app cannot be installed. Please retry later"). The build hint `ios.zsign=true` is set.

This is the error I got since I uninstalled the previous build, which throwed the error "The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iPadOS."

Both apps have the exact same build settings.

Do you have any idea how I could fix the problem?

### Update

This error occurs on the device when installing the app:

```
-[IXSCoordinatedAppInstall _finishAppInstallAtURL:result:error:]: Installation for <IXSCoordinatedAppInstall<0x105f0df90> identifier:de.klaus.todo uuid:4CEC79FF-8E9E-4174-A965-D4CE996D6EAC intent:IXCoordinatorIntentInitiating creator/appDRI:App Store importance:UserWaiting state:IXAppCoordinationStateWaitingForInstall> at path /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoordinationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/74BF0FD0-3847-439F-987A-EF8B52FD27A3/extract failed: Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=63 "Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement." UserInfo={LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, FunctionName=-[MIInstallableBundle _validateApplicationIdentifierForNewBundleSigningInfo:error:], SourceFileLine=899, NSLocalizedDescription=Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement.}
```

Comment: This seems to be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710009/codename-one-debug-builds-on-ios-15 can you answer the question in the thread?

Comment: I logged the device messages and found this one: Application is missing the application-identifier entitlement. (see issue description update). Do you know what this could mean?

Comment: Make sure your app id and provisioning are correct. Make sure they match the package name of the app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411862/756809

Comment: I will check. But it is strange, because I deployed this app a lot of times before - and is is available at the app store also. The same configuration worked with iOS 14 - but not with iOS 15. So something seems to be different - but I don‘t know what.

Comment: Do you still have an older device lying around. Does it still work?

Comment: Please file an issue in the CodenameOne issue tracker.  If possible provide a link to your .ipa file, and your provisioning profile.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have an older device at the moment. But I can ask around. I will file an issue with the ipa and provisioning profile.

Comment: I successfully installed the build on an iPhone 7 with iOS 14.8.1 and on a iPad Pro with iOS 14.8.1. But I cannot install the same build on an iPhone 11 with iOS 15.1 and a iPad Pro with iOS 15.1

Comment: I created an issue and added the ipa + provisioning profile there: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3524

Answer (score 0):

Looks like iOS 15.1 broke the signing process.  We have applied some patches to the build server and it appears to have fixed this issue.  Please try sending another build - and it should work.

Comment: Yes - now a new build can be installed :-)